# Flutter - Firstore returns null data even when data is there

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the data which stored in firestore database. But when I try to fetch the data it returns null.

Here is the code,

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDocumentInfo(String collectionName, String docId) async {
    DocumentSnapshot document = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName).doc(docId).get();
    print(document.data());
    Map<String, dynamic> docInfo = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return docInfo;
  }
```

[image]

Can anyone say what is the error? It gives the error "_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)"

Comment: What does `print(collectionName); print(docId);` show? Do these values exist in the database? Are there any other errors in the complete stacktrace? Also, did you enable read access in the database rules?

Answer (score 0):

Check if something related to this works ... it's not a snapshot but it'll give you the idea.

```
Future<void> addNewQuestion(Map AddQuestionData, File image) async {
        CommanDialog.showLoading();

    var pathimage = image.toString();
    var temp = pathimage.lastIndexOf('/');
    var result = pathimage.substring(temp + 1);
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('').child(result);
    var response = await ref.putFile(image);
    var imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    CommanDialog.hideLoading();

    try {
      CommanDialog.showLoading();
      var response = await firebaseInstance.collection('QuestionList').add({
        'QuestionId': AddQuestionData['QuestionId'],
        'QuestionText': AddQuestionData['QuestionText'],
        "QuestionImageURL": imageUrl,
        'AnswerA': AddQuestionData['AnswerA'],
        "AnswerB": AddQuestionData['AnswerB'],
        "AnswerC": AddQuestionData['AnswerC'],
        "AnswerD": AddQuestionData['AnswerD'],
        "AskedIn": AddQuestionData['AskedIn'],
        "SubjectName": AddQuestionData['SubjectName'],
        "ChapterName": AddQuestionData['ChapterName'],
        "CorrectAnswer": AddQuestionData['CorrectAnswer'],
      });
      CommanDialog.hideLoading();
      Get.back();
    } catch (exception) {
      CommanDialog.hideLoading();
    }
  }
```